# Adding ints to an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, random, int, append

I am trying to create a random number to add to an array (arr). I have looked around for answers but they all seem to not be working or be outdated. Here is what I have tried:

```
int[] arr = {};
int rand =  (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
arr = append(arr, rand);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work as there is a red line under append saying "The method append(int[], int) is undefined for the type new ActionListener(){}". Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You should read a basic tutorial about Arrays in Java.

Comment: From the tutorial on arrays (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html): An array is a container object that holds a **fixed number** of values of a single type. Read the tutorial.

Comment: Take a look to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html to learn how arrays are used in Java

Comment: You should consider using an `ArrayList` instead. You can't change the size of the array once you have created it.

Comment: If you used an ArrayList and used the add() method then it would append to the end of the array automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would first declare your array like so:

> int[] arr;

Do you know how many integers you will be storing?

> arr = new int[10];

You would then use a for loop to go through each element in the array.

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
  int rand = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
  arr[i] = rand;
}
```

From [Arrays (Java Docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: No worries. This was my first contribution on stackoverflow and I'm happy to be of assistance. In the case of an array for which you are unsure of the length though, it may be wise to go with the ArrayList object instead, as other users have suggested.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot "append" to an array: although array elements in Java are mutable, the length of the array is set at creation time, and cannot change later on.

If you need a collection that can change in size, use `ArrayList<Integer>` to append as many elements as you need; after that, you can convert the list to an array.

Comment: #append might be a method that creates a new array with sufficient size and appends whatever needs appended; the returned then is a reference to a new array

Answer (score 2):

In Java, arrays are fixed length, so you can't dynamically append to them.

If you want to append things to a list, you should use `Arraylist`.

```
List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int rand =  (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
arr.add(rand);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to 'append' elements to an array. You have to create a new array with the appropriate size, copy all the old elements and insert the new one(s).
Another way would be to use an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using List?

```
List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int rand =  (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
arr.add(rand);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Java compiler looks for methods in the same class as where you're calling them from. In this case, it seems to be an anonymous `ActionListener` class, so that's where it looks for the `append(int[], int)` method, but it can't find it.

Back to the goal you want to achieve. An array of primitive types (as your `int[]` is) does not have any methods. So we need a little help.

First we can convert the array to a `List<Integer>`, by using [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29). Next we can add new `int`s to that list by calling [`List.add(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29). Finally we can convert that List back to an `int[]` by calling [`List.toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29). All in one, that would look like this:

```
int[] arr = {};
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
list.add((int) Math.round(Math.random() * 100));
arr = list.toArray(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function called generaterandomInt.

```
private float generateRandomInt(int min, int max) {
    return min + (max - min) * random.nextInt();
}
```

Now you just have to implement this into your loop

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
  int rand = generateRandomInt(0, 100);
  arr[i] = rand;
}
```